# Scala: Is it possible to remove implicit context in the function?

Tags: scala

Suppose, I have a signature like this:

```
def mergesort[T](xs: Array[T])
                (implicit ord: T => Ordered[T], 
                          man: Manifest[T]): Array[T] = {
  //...
}
```

Is it possible to throw away the implicit part `(implicit ord: T => Ordered[T], man: Manifest[T])` and keep function working?

I can use `T <% Ordered[T]` but in that case I still need `man: Manifest[T]`.

Comment: What do you mean throw it away? Why is it even needed in the first place? It's not really clear what you want, here.

Comment: I just realized I totally misinterpreted what you were asking.

Comment: Note that view bounds (`<%`) are deprecated: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7629

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write:

```
def mergesort[T <% Ordered[T] : Manifest](xs: Array[T]): Array[T] = {
  //...
}
```

but understand that you are not actually "getting rid of" the implicit argument list, you are just hiding it using syntactic sugar. The compiler will simply (in effect) convert this internally into the original form.